# Sync Edge and Chrome UIDs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, uid, microsoft-edge-extension

I have a Chrome extension where I make use of a user's UID to keep track of their content (to prevent the need of having them sign up). I noticed that, understandably, Edge's UID does get reported but it's different than the one for the user in Chrome even if they use the same email address for both accounts and, less understandably, even if they are signed into their Chrome account when downloading the extension from Chrome's webstore.

Is there any possible way I can sync the two via email address or something? Or is there potentially a way for users to force their UID to be changed to one that they set (so that they can manually update their UID to match the one that Chrome gives them - or the opposite way, updating their Chrome UID to match Edge's)?

Here's the code I use in my background script to get the UIDs:

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(info) {
  console.log(info.id); // something like 203705265093101
});
```

I am using the latest public version of Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Can you please show any code sample how you are getting the UID for both browsers and what result you got from both browsers and what is the expected output? Also inform us, which version of Chrome and which version of Edge browser you are using for this test?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I updated the post with that information.

Comment: As per my understanding, both browsers are different products from different companies even if they are using a similar browser engine. So because of that reason, they are showing the different UID. At present, I am not available with any document which can confirm this thing. Further, I will try to discuss this issue with other senior engineers and try to know their opinion on it.